# Is it any possibility to create login in .NET Maui?

Tags: .net, identityserver4, maui

I am looking for any possibility to create a login in .NET Maui Desktop App. The identity provider should be IdentityServer. Is it any sample how to do it? I tried with oidc client, but failed because of redirect uri.

Comment: Yes.  This is such a vague and broad question, it's really impossible to answer beyond that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can follow this article https://auth0.com/blog/add-authentication-to-dotnet-maui-apps-with-auth0/ . It explains basics. Or this you tube explains integration with Identity server as you required.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example for Xamarin [Authentication and Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization) should work for maui. If there is a redirect uri issue it could be you haven't registered it in IdentityServer